# Javascript replace special chars { } "

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Why does this code fail replacing the special chars:

http://jsfiddle.net/TTfzu/26/

```
var strOutput = 'aaa { " } '; 

strOutput.replace(/{/g, "");
strOutput.replace(/}/g, "");
strOutput.replace(/"/g, "");

document.write( strOutput );
```

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace` doesn't change its argument, it returns a new string. You have to assign the result somewhere otherwise it's lost:

```
var strOutput = 'aaa { " } '; 

strOutput = strOutput.replace(/{/g, "");
strOutput = strOutput.replace(/}/g, "");
strOutput = strOutput.replace(/"/g, "");

document.write( strOutput );
```

or just use a character class `[...]` in your regexp:

```
var strOutput = 'aaa { " } '; 
strOutput = strOutput.replace(/[{}"]/g, "");
```

Comment: Good answer. To my surprise, /{/ is a legal RE in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks I thought the replaced string is put back to the caller. I can accept in 3 min...

Comment: Thanks for the link, it confirms what I thought, that this is highly dependent on the regex engine implementation... I avoid to quote safe chars like " but I prefer to quote these special chars even if the context isn't ambiguous (a safe context is between square brackets, of course, for most chars).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to catch the result from the replace. (And you can chain your replaces.)

```
var strOutput = 'aaa { " } '; 

strOutput = strOutput.replace(/{/g, "").replace(/}/g, "").replace(/"/g, "");

document.write( strOutput );
```

Btw you can make it as simple as this:

```
strOutput = strOutput..replace(/({|"|})/g, "");
```

---

As of @Alnitak comment:

```
strOutput = strOutput..replace(/[{}"]/g, "");
```

Comment: that last line is a horrible way to replace multiple characters.  This is _exactly_ what character classes were designed for.

Answer (score 1):

Per other answers, you need to use the *result* of `.replace`.

However you don't need three calls, you should be using:

```
strOutput = strOutput.replace(/[{}"]/g, '');
```

where the `[...]` is a *character class* which matches any individual character in that set.  Within such a class the only characters that need to be escaped are `^-]\`